# How would I get the names and id's out of this object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object called `@groups`

When I enter `@groups` into the console it returns this:

```
[#<Group id: 2, name: "another test group", creator_id: 6, updater_id: 6, created_at: "2013-11-22 17:04:14", updated_at: "2013-11-22 17:04:14">, #<Group id: 1, name: "test group", creator_id: 6, updater_id: 6, created_at: "2013-11-20 17:50:28", updated_at: "2013-11-20 17:50:28">]
```

I want to make an select field and populate it with each group using the `options_for_select()` method

So, I was going to try to get the names and id's of each group and populate it that way but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than mapping the attributes you want out of an array, you should do this the rails way by using either the [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) or, even easier, you can use [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) in your form.

Comment: I didn't know about options_from_collection_for_select and had forgotten about collection_select. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Good call @matt - I was answering the Ruby question, nice catch on the Rails side of it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `map` for this:

`@groups.map {|group| [group.name, group.id]}`

This will return an array of arrays, with each containing `[group.name, group.id]`.